# Bug? Consecutive URLs point to different URL in edit vs view mode

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, editor

Looking at https://stackoverflow.com/a/1768114/14731, if you hover the mouse over the 4 hyperlinks at the top of the answer they all map to [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0015T963C](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0015T963C) but if you edit the post and try the same you will see each hyperlink now points to a different (correct) address.

Is this a bug? Shouldn't the links point to different addresses as seen in edit mode?

Comment: Not really a bug - it's intended behaviour. The HTML for the links (when I view them) are of the form `<a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0015T963C" rel="noreferrer">http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/glance/B0015T963C</a>`. The Amazon link in your question is doing the same. I guess it's a bug that the edit view doesn't do this - for consistency.

Comment: @WaiHaLee The behavior although intended seems wrong. The answer resolves around 4 different kinds of links but Stackoverflow is rewriting them to a single kind. This defeats the entire point of the discussion. Is there a way to instruct Stackoverflow to leave the URL alone?

Comment: I guess if you wanted to override it you could format `as code` instead of a link? I don't know of another way but a developer/moderator may know otherwise.